# Check if a page loads after a click in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

My app is to check for a webpage if they change their content.

Normally it will perform clicking the Next button every x seconds (it's currently 7s). But recently I realized sometimes the webpage didn't load after the click. It caused the app to stop running because it is still clicking Next but couldn't realize that the webpage didnt load.

The webpage's URL and all the elements remain the same after the click, no different element to compare or find.

My click Next function:

```
def click_next_button(driver, timeout=15):
    next_button_locator = (By.XPATH, "//button[@title='Go to next page']")
    next_button = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(next_button_locator))
    
    # Scroll the next_button into view
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", next_button)

    # Use ActionChains to move to the element and click it
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    actions.move_to_element(next_button).click().perform()
```

A small clue is this element:

```
<body data-wc-domready="true" data-wc-timers="false" data-wc-ajaxp="false" class="wc-rtc-gum"><noscript><p>You must have JavaScript enabled to use this application.</p></noscript>
```

The DOMready value will change between false and true quite fast when the webpage loads. But I dont know how to take advantage of it.

A refresh might solve the problem. But I'm asking if there are any way to check if the webpage loads after the click without refreshing. If not then refresh is the last option. I'm very appreciated and TIA.

Comment: Check whether `document.readyState` is "complete"

Comment: @JishanShaikh but if the webpage didn't load after the click I think the document.readyState is still "complete" from the previous run? Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Then we can use some sort of combination with checking for the presence of a specific element on the page, with document.readyState